# How to attach an event to an already created object of a class instead creating new

Tags: c#

I have 'MainWindow' form which is an MdiContainer and with a group of buttons, button1 loads 'DesignTools' form as a child form, this has got some set of buttons as well. There are some common buttons on both the forms. Attached events to the  buttons on Child form and want to raise same events from the buttons of 'MainWindow'. Attaching the event to the newly created object is not giving any result, like the below. So, trying to attach the event to an already created object of 'MainWindow' , but unable to find out a way to do. 
I have:

```
MainWindow.cs
public class MainWindow :Form
 {
    public event EventHandler event1 = delegate { }; 
    public MainWindow  mainWindowSM{get;set;}
    public PEMainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
        ...
    }
    InitializeComponent()
    {
      .....
      this.BtnNudgeDown.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.event1);
      this.mainWindowSM = new MainWindow();
    }
    private void BtnDesignTools_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      DesignTools designer = new DesignTools();
    }
 }
```

And I have DesignTools.cs

```
public class DesignTools : Form 
{ 
 public DesignTools()
 {
  MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow(); //Creating new instance of MainWindow, I think this doesn't work
  mainWindow.event1 += this.BtnNudgeDown_Click;
 }
 private void BtnNudgeDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    ...
 }
}
```

This attempt is not raising the event.
How to attach the event to the already created object? Tried creating a property in MainWindow and setting object to that, but again its becoming new object.

Comment: Can you be more specific on the location of the problem and what the actual problem is?

Comment: Your code seems to be very convoluted. You really do need to describe the desired behaviour of your code.

Comment: Pass the `MainWindow` as constructor parameter to  `DesignTools`. It is ugly; but it will work.

Comment: You don't attach events to an object. You attach event handlers to an object's event.

Comment: @Enigmativity, A Button on MainWindow should raise the event that is in DesignTools.

Comment: @M.K - Can you please describe the desired behaviour of your code? Just saying "A Button on MainWindow should raise the event that is in DesignTools" isn't enough. It needs to be more like "I start the form Blah and when the user clicks the button foo the form Woohoo starts, and then any text changes in the textbox Qaz on Blah needs to be handled by the text_changed method on Woohoo."

Comment: @Enigmativity Edited my question and explained more specific.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this. Instantiate the designtools (once)
and call the btnNudgeDown_click

```
MainWindow.cs
public class MainWindow :Form
 {
    DesignTools designer;
    public event EventHandler event1 = delegate { }; 
    public MainWindow  mainWindowSM{get;set;}
    public PEMainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
        ...
    }
    InitializeComponent()
    {
      .....          
      this.mainWindowSM = new MainWindow();
    }
    private void BtnDesignTools_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      if (designer == null)
      {
          designer = new DesignTools();
      }

      designer.BtnNudgeDown_Click(this, e);
    }
 }

public class DesignTools : Form 
{ 
 public DesignTools()
 {

 }
 private void BtnNudgeDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    ...
 }
}
```

Comment: The basic solution is indeed having the same instance of `MainWindow`. I just want to add that if `DesignTools` has a shorter lifetime than `MainWindow`, you're in for a memory leak if you do not deregister from the event once `DesignTools` is disposed.

Comment: good point. but i checked it in the Designtools there is no event called. only a private function with identical parameters. :). I don't see any mem leak occuring here.. if you can detect it please specify where :)